# How can I stop JsonSlurper from converting objects/maps to arrays?

Tags: groovy, jsonslurper

I have a JSON response item from a web service that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "field1":"value",
        "field2":"value2",
        "field3":"value3",
        "field4":"value4"
    },
    {
        "field1":"value",
        "field2":"value2",
        "field3":"value3",
        "field4":"value4"
    },
    ...
]
```

Before conversion my response string looks normal (like this):

```
[{"field1":"value","field2":"value2","field3":"value3", "field4":"value4"},{...},...]
```

However after I run `def allData = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)`

and then log `allData` it appears that it's converting my objects to arrays:

**Example:**

```
[["field1":"value","field2":"value2","field3":"value3", "field4":"value4"],[...],...]
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

*Edit:*

**Imports:**
`import groovy.json.JsonSlurper`

Comment: Your input is being converted to an array of Maps.  What did you want it to become?

Comment: I want an array of maps. It's being converted into an array of arrays (`{` vs `[`)

Comment: The groovy syntax for map is [key: value].  This is working exactly as you want it to.

Comment: Nomenclature aside, it's clear that I want a JSON-like object

Comment: You say you want an array of maps, and that's what this is.  It's not clear what the problem is.  What is a "JSON-like object"?

Comment: I'm looking for objects to be surrounded by curly braced (like it is in JSON) (https://www.json.org/). So the structure would be [ { ... }, { ... } ]

Comment: That's just the string representation (toString()) of a Map in Groovy.  You could write your own method to output a different String but it won't change the fact that the underlying data structure is a collection of maps.

Comment: FYI chat is blocked where I work, I found out when I tried to continue in chat.  Sorry to have to continue in comments!

Comment: No worries - it's blocked for me too. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify the (admittedly long) comments above for anyone who has this problem in the future:

That is an array of maps.  The confusion came from a difference in String representation between JSON and Groovy, but the underlying data structure was already correct.